# Handling embedded newline characters in log messages using log4net

Tags: log4net, c#-2.0

When a log message contains embedded new line characters, then the alignment of such log messages is not proper in the log file.

For example, if I am using the conversion pattern: 
    [%-5level] %message%newline

and if I log an exception Stack Trace which contains embedded new line characters, or any other multi line log message, then the additional lines in the message start from the beginning of the line.

Is it possible that for each such additional line, the conversion pattern is followed, and the text indented appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

I do it the following way:

```
void Log(string message, int levelsDeep)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0; i < levelsDeep; i++)
       sb.Append(" ");

   string spacer = sb.ToString();

   string msg = message.Replace("\r\n", "\r\n" + spacer);
   msg = "\r\n" + msg + "\r\n";   //the prefix and suffix newline characters ensure that this and the next message starts in a new line and is not impacted by the 'spacer' from this message.

   // call log4net functions to log the 'msg'

}
```